# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.#QO

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In Python 2.7, I am trying to convert a large pandas dataframe into a numpy array with float values.

I tried:

```
df = np.array(df).astype(float)
```

but I got:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.#QO
```

what should I do?

```
df.info()

dtypes: float64(156), int64(370), object(1)
```

Comment: Can you please a part of the dataframe (that is relevant) , and the expected output?

Comment: Try `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` however it would be useful to find the duff rows so I would look at `df[df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).isnull()]` and check which values it's unhappy with

Comment: Is your df containing mixed dtypes such as strings? can you post output from `df.info()`

Comment: see my reply update. the dataframe is quite big

Comment: Well it looks like one of the columns is probably string, are you expecting this to be convertible to a float? Also most of your df is already numeric is there a reason you need all the columns to be a float dtype?

Comment: the 'object' column contains almost only floats, except some weird string values '1.#QO'. Thanks, I will try to correct them. I want floats to feed a regression algorithm.

Comment: it worked, thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
df.info()
```

I identified that my column 'DistTopo' had type 'object', instead of float or int.

Then I entered:

```
df['DistTopo']
```

and I saw one value '1.#QO' which was string.

So I made:

```
df=df.replace('1.#QO',1)
```

and I got a dataframe with floats and ints.

There are certainly better methods, but this one was enough for me.